# React useEffect not firing and Layout doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect, use-state

folks!

I'm trying to change an array and pass it to a useState function. The problem is that when I pass the modified array as the parameter to useState, the DOM doesn't catch the change and useEffect doesnt too.

Theres a way to reproduce the problem:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [mark, setMark] = useState([]);

  function ChangeValue() {
    const arr = mark;
    arr.push("hello");
    console.log(arr);
    setMark((mark) => {
      return arr;
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ADDED VALUE");
  }, [mark]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {mark.map((item) => {
        return <h3>{item}</h3>;
      })}
      <button onClick={() => ChangeValue()}>Add More</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There's a sandbox to the code above: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-cache-kgfkv?file=/App.js:0-562

As you can see, the function aways logs the new state correctly, but useEffect doesn't fire and the DOM doesnt change.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
const arr = [...mark]
```

instead of

```
const arr = mark
```

because when you do just `const arr = mark` it does not creates a new array but a new reference to the same array. When you do `const arr = [...mark]` it creates a new array everytime with the elements in the mark array.

Answer (score 0):

You mutate the state, instead create a copy as React re-renders components based on shallow comparison (`===`) with the previous state (read docs for more info).

Also you should assign a [`key` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) when rendering array of components:

```
export default function App() {
  const [mark, setMark] = useState([]);

  function changeValue() {
    setMark((mark) => [...mark, "hello"]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ADDED VALUE");
  }, [mark]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {mark.map((item, index) => {
        return <h3 key={index}>{item}</h3>;
      })}

      <button onClick={changeValue}>Add More</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hugle-r7mzq?file=/App.js

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to @Dennis Vash's answer, but shorter and probably closer to a real scenario (because you probably want to add a dynamic value to your mark array).

```
export default function App() {
    const [mark, setMark] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('ADDED VALUE');
    }, [mark]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            {mark.map((item, index) => {
                return <h3 key={index}>{item}</h3>;
            })}
            <button onClick={(event) => setMark([...mark, event.target.value])}>Add More</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```